# What will be done with ARC besides inserting the retain and release

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

What will be done with ARC besides inserting the retain and release? It's said that ARC will optimize the code?

Comment: I'd suggestion you refer to [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) which outlines everything that's changed.

Comment: In addition to the things matt describes below, it also automatically initializes stack variables to `nil`. Before, if you declared some variable, e.g. `NSString *string;`, you had no assurances what it would be until you explicitly set it to something. Also, `dealloc` now automatically calls its `super` implementation, so if you even need `dealloc` at all, you at least no longer have to remember to call `[super dealloc]`, too. There are other considerations, too, all outlined in the above doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Inserting the retain and release" is in fact almost all that ARC does (especially if you include autorelease). In effect, it follows [The Golden Rules of Memory Management](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_the_golden_rules_of_memory_management) so that you don't have to.

It does also add one further feature: it introduces [automatic nilification of weak references](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_retain_cycles_and_weak_references), to prevent dangling pointers.

Comment: Although that simple thing is a huge weight off of developers. You had to learn to be very disciplined with your retains and releases and if you messed up, you either leaked memory or your program crashed in strange ways that were hard to debug. It's hard to overstate the benefits of ARC over manual reference counting. It's been long enough since I've written non-arc code that I would probably screw it up now.